# CAlling a c# code from quality center

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center

I want to call a c# code from quality center. The XML files are residing in quality center I want to know about any driver,code that will give that xml data to that c# code.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via workflow code:

```
Set CSharpCode = CreateObject("YourNameSpace.YourStaticClass")
```

then use the methods in your C# code like this:

```
CSharpCode.YourMethod
```

You can pass the XML data to the C# end as a parameter.

In the dll you have to ornament the class you are calling from with the attribute `[ComVisible(true)]`

Some of these actions may be not so trivial if you are not familiar already. I recommend reading [HP forum](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Community/ct-p/sws-QC) as well as [TDForum](http://tdforums.tdadmins.com/).